# How can I set the terminal to not automatically go to the last line if there the output in the terminal has been updated?

Tags: command-line, ssh, tty, putty, stdout

I have some programs that are continuously outputting data on the terminal.

I however want to be able to scroll up and down while the program is outputting all this data to the terminal, but every time the program outputs a new line the terminal automatically scrolls down to the last line.

EDIT:

I do not have a GUI interface installed and I cannot install one. 
I am running the programs on a VM hosted on a server provided by my uni and I connect through SSH.

Comment: open a `terminal --> preferences --> profile --> edit --> scrolling` __unselect scroll on output__. Hope it does the trick

Comment: @George already posted that as answer.

Comment: @George  Thanks for the answers but I do not have a GUI installed and it is not possible to install one.

Comment: @yoyo_fun since you said you are using a server, not desktop, you might want to mention that this question is TTY-specific and not for GUI terminal emulators

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, there is no way to make TTY output stuff AND not scroll at the same time. What can be done is to freeze it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> shortcut, and scroll all the text you need using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Pg_Up</kbd>/<kbd>Pg_Down</kbd> keys, and then unfreeze with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> shortcut. More historical explanation of this shortcut's purpose can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137842/85039

Alternatively, consider sending output of the program you use to file and use different TTY to read the contents of that file.

If your University has `screen` program installed, you can enter copy mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> . In copy mode, the screen doesn't scroll until you exit it.

Comment: Thanks for the asnswer but I do not have bine GUI installed and I do not have the privileges to install one.

Comment: @yoyo_fun edited my answer, made it TTY-specific. Please review